# How to plot data from a .mat file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

My matfile with data is 256x150000x11 and I would like 150,000 to be the x-axis in milliseconds and for there to be 11 lines on the graph. The y-axis should be a voltage value already coming from inside the file. One graph should represent 1/256. So technically I should have 256 graphs with the same labeled axises and number of graph lines. Could you help me figure out how to plot this in Matlab? Here is my code:

```
function importfile(fileToRead1)
%IMPORTFILE(FILETOREAD1)
%  Imports data from the specified file
%  FILETOREAD1:  file to read

%  Auto-generated by MATLAB on 04-Mar-2019 07:15:26

% Import the file
%newData1 = load('-mat', fileToRead1);
newData1 = load('Sub21.mat')

% Create new variables in the base workspace from those fields.
vars = fieldnames(newData1);
for i = 1:length(vars)
    assignin('base', vars{i}, newData1.(vars{i}));
end
[n,p] = size(newData1)
t = 1:n;
plot(t,newData1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correct you can plot it in a for loop running from 1 to 256.

```
newData1 = load('Sub21.mat')

for n=1:256
plot(newdata(n,:,1)) %Plotting n of 256, all 150000 and 1st of the 11 lines
hold on;
plot(newdata(n,:,2))
hold on;
plot(newdata(n,:,3))
hold on;
.
.
.
plot(newdata(n,:,11))
hold on;
xlabel('milisec')
ylabel('voltage')
legend('name1','name2', .... , 'name11')
end
% or maybe two for loops
for n=1:256
for m=1:11
    plot(newdata(n,:,m)) %Plotting n of 256, all 150000 and m of the 11 lines
    hold on;
end 
end
```

You may wanna use subplot, so you don't end up with 256 figures.

Can you send some of the data?

Comment: `newData1` here is a struct array. `load` either assigns the variables in the workspace, or if you use a return variable it assigns them to fields of a struct.